# Light web application in slow network conditions

Tags: html, jquery, node.js, performance, gprs

I want would develop web-based software for my board. I'm using HTML5, Bootstrap, jQuery for front end and REST Server using Node JS. I use also JSON and AJAX. The Requirements asks me that web application must work also in slow networks condition, like GPRS, 2G etc. Actually, I simulate slow network condition using Firefox settings and I get bad result.

Are there some best practices to implement correctly a light version of my web application, which work in slow networks conditions?

For example, I tried to develop Light web page without Bootstrap and using only basic CSS code, minify JS and reduce reduce data exchange between client and server  but I don't have other solutions actually.

I cannot use CDN to get Bootstrap and other library, I must use only local library and it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Source](https://medium.com/@manojsingh047/light-weight-websites-98a79249035)

Configure the server to use GZIP compression.

Optimize Image

Deliver images responsively

Use HTTP2

Resource prioritization — rel=preload, rel=preconnect

Minify text assets

Sprite images to reduce the number of requests

Use HTML5 semantic elements

Refrain from using huge CSS libraries/frameworks

Look for leaner JS library alternatives